# initialization and spring integration channels

Tags: java, spring-integration

I need to load bunch of data right after spring initialization, just once. 
In my scheme i have service activator that works with control bus (sends messages to control bus channel). 
Creating service that sends this bunch of data after initialization doesnt help, this [96221-jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter-for-doing-only-a-single-query-at-runtime](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/96221-jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter-for-doing-only-a-single-query-at-runtime) doesnt help also - Im getting `org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers`. Tried several ways, including `BeanPostProcessor`, `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` but still have feeling channels arent initilized yet at moment of method call. 
Any ways to solve this problem?

upd: `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` worked as magic. Thx for advice

upd2:
config of problem part below. The trick is in *cbManager*, that sends message to controlBus, calling method of *providerManager* bean. (`"@providerManager.add(headers.providerConfig)"`). 
Works good with http-inbound part, but *jdbcPoller* task is to do same in initialization. `ApplicationListener` solved my problem but if there is something i dont know or alternatives, Id be glad to know

```
    <int:control-bus input-channel="controlBusMainChannel"/>

    <int:channel id="controlBusMainChannel" />
    <int:channel id="cbRequests" />
    <int:channel id="cbReplies" />
    <int:channel id="postRequests" />

    <bean id="cbManager" class ="com.dph.hlss.bus.ViaBusProviderManager">
        <constructor-arg name="channel" ref="controlBusMainChannel" />
    </bean>

     <int-http:inbound-gateway id="cbPostController"
        request-channel="cbRequests"
        reply-channel="cbReplies"
        path="/controlbus/providers" 
        request-payload-type="com.dph.hlss.bus.providermanager.model.ProviderAddDTO"
        supported-methods="POST"
        payload-expression="body"   
    >
        <int-http:header name="requestId" expression="T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()"/>
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="cbRequests" ref="cbInbound"/> 

    <int:gateway id="cbInbound" default-request-channel="cbInbRequests"  error-channel="cbErrorHandleMessages" />

    <int:transformer input-channel="cbErrorHandleMessages" output-channel="cbReplies" ref="errorTransformer" method="transform"/>

    <int:payload-type-router input-channel="cbInbRequests" >
        <int:mapping type="com.dph.hlss.bus.providermanager.model.ProviderAddDTO" channel="postRequests"/>
    </int:payload-type-router>

    <int:service-activator id="addProvider" input-channel="postRequests" output-channel="cbReplies" ref="cbManager" method="add" />

    <bean id="providerManager" class="com.dph.hlss.bus.ProviderCommandManagment" >
        <property name="providerManager" ref="searchProviderManager"/>
        <property name="factory" ref="abstractProvidersFactory" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcPoller" class="com.dph.hlss.bus.JDBCPoller" >
        <property name="accepter" ref="cbManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.dph.interfaces.spring.SpringBeanLauncher">
        <property name="launchableBean" ref="jdbcPoller" />
        <property name="contextId" value="/search-facade" />
        <property name="rootContextId" value="org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending the data too soon.

Implement `ApplicationListener` and send the data when the `ContextRefreshedEvent` is received.

Comment: thanks, it worked. Didnt realize BeanPostProcessor works after bean initialization, not after whole context

Answer (score 1):

> Dispatcher has no subscribers

Says that you have some `SubscribableChannel` (e.g. just ), which doesn't have any endpoint to receive messages from it, or that endpoint isn't started (`auto-startup="false"`).

Show your, config, please, to understand what's going.

Comment: advice of Gary Russel worked for me, doesnt seem its some subscriber lost, but in case i missed some specific details, i added config, will appreciate any information

Comment: No, everything is correct. Sorry for confuse. Just keep in mind my comment: it's tipical issue, when you lose some subscribtion.